c# m:n model relationships (razor pages)
I am trying to establish a m:n relationship between my actor model (actor.cs) and (movie.cs). I have already created a junction table actormovie.cs with corresponding FK’s and navigation properties to these models. All three models have been scaffolded with CRUD pages. I am trying to enforce mandatory participation across both actor, as well as movie, so an actor is acting in 1 or more movies, and a movie has 1 or more actors.I am looking for a m:n relationship with both entities having mandatory participation. My question is, how can I enforce the participation of their entities? Currently, the user has to navigate to my junction table create page (ActorMovie) to map an actor to a movie, which doesn’t seem to “enforce” the participation across both entities that is needed.
// actor model
    public class Actor
   {
       public int actorID { get; set; }
       public string? actorName { get; set; }
       public double actorRating { get; set; }

       public int actorMovieCount { get; set; }

       public double actorEXP { get; set; }

       public List <ActorMovie>? ActorMovies { get; set; }
   }

// movie model

   public class Movie
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string? Title { get; set; }
       [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
       [DataType(DataType.Date)]
       public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
       public string? Genre { get; set; }
       [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
       public decimal Price { get; set; }
       public string Rating { get; set; } = string.Empty;

       public List<ActorMovie>? ActorMovies { get; set; }
   }

// junction table
    public class ActorMovie
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Actor? Actor { get; set; }
        public int? actorID { get; set; }

        public Movie? Movie { get; set; }
        public int? MovieID { get; set; }
    }


I have ran my application and created actors and well as movies from the create pages of both, but I have to navigate to create page of the junction table to match an actor to a movie, vice versa. I am looking for a way to mandate their entity participation upon creation.

seems tags not correct it is not razor problem. Please paraphrase and format your question to improve readability.

For this purpose, you need to implement more integration and link between actor and movie in CRUD processes, so that users can't add new movie or actor without establishing connection in interface table.
For example, you can use the form controller to limit the user:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Actor actor, int[] SelectedMovies)
{
    if (SelectedMovies == null || !SelectedMovies.Any())
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Movies", "At least one movie must be selected.");
        return View(actor);
    }

    foreach (var movieId in SelectedMovies)
    {
        actor.ActorMovies.Add(new ActorMovie { MovieId = movieId });
    }

    _context.Actors.Add(actor);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}


This will create new movies every time.
